# Let L be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space V over a field F, with p in F[T]. Show that Ker(p(L)) = {0} iff gcd(p, $\mu$) = 1

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm struggling to prove this problem, mostly because I'm not quite certain what the minimal polynomial, $\mu$ is. Wikipedia says it's the least monic polynomial that gives $\mu$(L) = 0, but then this leads to some confusion with this situation where Ker(p(L)) = {0}. I know this means p takes the zero map to zero, but I'm not sure if the minimal polynomial is specified for only nonzero maps or not. I would greatly appreciate some guidance on this problem, as I've been hitting some roadblocks.

My latest attempt at a solution, which is incomplete:

($\Rightarrow$) V is finite, so there exists a unique minimal polynomial for L. Since Ker(p(L)) = {0}, we have that $\mu$ does not divide p as (t - L) is not a factor of p.

At this point, I'm stuck. I know (t - L) is not a factor of p, but can I assume t is? How do I find the gcd from this?

($\Leftarrow$) Let gcd(p, $\mu$) = 1. Then there exist polynomials a and b such that ap + b$\mu$ = 1, which implies a(L)p(L) + b(L)$\mu$(L) = 1 (the identity map) and thus a(L)p(L) = 1 since $\mu$(L) = 0. Thus p(L) is a constant polynomial.

But I'm not sure how to get that the kernel contains only the zero map. Also, what does it mean for a constant polynomial to have a kernel? I know polynomials can be thought of as functions, but does this just mean a constant polynomial is some scalar multiplied by the identity map which would imply the kernel is zero iff the polynomial is the zero polynomial? I tried a different approach for the reverse direction (below), but I'm not sure it's the right way to approach the problem (not sure I actually proved anything).

($\Leftarrow$) Let gcd(p, $\mu$) = 1. Thus P(L) = 0 iff L = 0 iff Ker(p(L)) = {0}, as otherwise (t - L) would be a factor of p and gcd(p, $\mu$) would not equal one.

The last one feels correct, but also too easy. Would someone please help me see what I'm missing? I would prefer not to get the answer, just the insight that I'm missing (which is probably something big). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I guess You need to understand better what $p(L)$ for a polynomial $p\in F[X]$ means: $L$ is an $F$-linear map of $V$ into itself. Therefore the powers $L^k:=L\circ L\circ\ldots\circ L$ are $F$-linear maps $V\rightarrow V$ too; here $\circ$ means composition of maps.

Also multiplikation of an $F$-linear map $V\rightarrow V$ by a constant $a\in F$ yields an $F$-linear map $V\rightarrow V$.

Together this gives $p(L)$ a meaning: namely

$
p(L)=a_0\mathrm{id_V}+a_1L+a_2L^2+\ldots a_nL^n
$

where powers and multiplikation with constants are understood as explained. Hence $p(L)$ is an $F$-linear map $V\rightarrow V$.

Extension of the post:

suppose that the minimal polynomial $\mu$ of $L$ has the proper factorization $\mu=p_1p_2$ in $F[X]$. Then the equation $0=\mu(L)=p_1(L)\circ p_2(L)$ shows, that the image of the linear map $p_2(L)$ lies in the kernel of $p_1(L)$. Moreover this image is not $0$, because then $p_2(L)$ would be the zero-map, that is $p_2(L)=0$ contradicting the assumption about the factorization. One concludes that $p_1(L)$ is not injective.

I think this is the direction into which the proof should go.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm afraid I'm still stuck. I understand what you're saying here, but I can't quite see how I can use it. Are you saying I'm wrong to focus on factorizations here? Again, thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Yes, you must be careful with factorization arguments, since plugging in $L$ moves things into the ring $F[L]$, which has zero-divisors. So polynomials behave strangely here.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep working at it. Thank you again for your help. I can't upvote you since I don't have enough reputation, but I appreciate your help.